# how to create a room based on 2 users in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

My goal is to create a one to one chat based on two different users. The only way that I could think of is to use socket.io rooms

But the problem right now is that how do i create unique room?

For example

```
socket.on('join', function(room) {
   socket.join(room);
});
```

Do i need to emit the room from the client, if so , how do I make it unique. Imagine there are thousands of users.

The chat application, is similar like facebook chat application. Where you can chat one on one.

Do i need redis or mongodb to store the room? Anyone of you who have experience using socket.io in scale, please do share your opinion

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

A room always will be unique, when you do `socket.join('roomname')` if the room not exist it will created and this socket will join it, if exist the socket just will join it.

So if you want that client A join in the room where is client B for example, from client A you  can send a event like:

```
socket.emit('joinroom', roomname);
```

On sever:

```
socket.on('joinroom', function(data){
     socket.join(data)
  })
```

Anyway when a socket connect , it create and join his own room automatically , the name of this room will be the id of the socket, so i think is not neccessary create new rooms for a chat based on two different users.

Everything that you need is link the socket id with a permanent property of the user.

EDIT:

I leave you here a simple chat app example where you can open multiple conversations:

server.js: https://gist.github.com/pacmanmulet/b30d26b9e932316f54b2

index.html: https://gist.github.com/pacmanmulet/6481791089effb79f25f

You can test it here :https://chat-socket-io-example.herokuapp.com/

I did not use rooms, it have more sense when you want emit to a group of sockets, not to a only one.
Hope you can understand better my idea with that.

Comment: Its not necessary to create a room? why is that?

Comment: because you can use the created one, well if you want I can do a example app that do it

Comment: Thank you for helping me, yeah if possible could show me an example app?

Comment: This is amazing, let me integrate it to my web app.

Comment: Hello to everybody,

I was searching for clues based on this idea, I just wanted to say thank you very much for your clear explanations :)

Best Reguards

Answer (score 4):

you need to store the room number somewhere(any database).You have to do this because you have to keep your server stateless.

Let us assume that you are creating a private chat only for two people.The room number has to be unique. so one approach is to use the user's email id and join them to create a new string and emit it back to the users.this is tricky because we don't know the order in which the strings are joined. so we join them by a string not used in normal email name(eg :'"@!@!@!!@!@!@!').we can split it on the server side and compare emit the results.

The actual message body will be

```
   {
        room:a@gmail.comb@gmail.com,
        from:a,
        message:'hi buddy how are you?'
    }
```

#### CLIENT side code

```
const roomName = a@gmail.com+'@!@!2!@!@"+b@gmail.com
socket.emit('room', { room: roomName });
    this.socket.on('joined', data => {
        console.log('i have joined', data.room)
        store the room name room: data.room })
    })
socket.on('chat',data=>console.log(`received chat from ${data.from} from the message room ${data.room}`)
```

used '@!@!2@!@' just because we can separate them on the server side and check if the room already exists.

#### SERVER side code

```
 const room =[]//this variable you have store in database and retrieve it when needed.
socket.on('room',data=>{
        if(room.length!=0){
            const temp = data.room.split('!@!@2@!@!').reverse().join('!@!@2@!@!');
            if(room.includes(temp)){
                socket.join(temp)
                console.log('joined room',temp)
                socket.emit('joined',{room:temp})
                console.log(room);
            } else if(room.includes(data.room)){
                socket.join(data.room)
                console.log('joined room', data.room)
                socket.emit('joined', { room: data.room})
                console.log(room);

            }
        }else{
            socket.join(data.room);
            room.push(data.room)
            console.log('joined room',data.room);
            socket.emit('joined', { room: data.room })
            console.log(room);
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to do a [minimal example](https://github.com/jameshiew/simple-chat-websockets) of where you can only be in one room at a time (apart from your default `socket.id` room) and only other sockets in the same room as you will receive your messages. Also you can change rooms.

The basic premise is, if socket A is in room 'xyz' and so is socket B, on the server side you can do `socket.to('xyz').emit('message', 'hello')` for socket A, and socket B will receive the message, but another connected socket C which isn't in room 'xyz' won't.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but does the example let say, User A clicks on User B to chat with him, and later on User B clicks on User to chat with him. Will they be in the same room?

Comment: All room joining and leaving is done server side, so User A and User B would need to notify the server that they want to talk to each other. You could have a list of users on the client's webpage and have it so that clicking on a user causes a `socket.emit('request to chat', clickedUsername)`. On the server you would then have to work out when two users have clicked on each other's name, and then call the `.join(someString)` on each of their sockets where `someString` is unique. Then (server-side) you could do `socket.to('someString').emit('message', ...)` calls to send messages between them.

Comment: Let me write a simple chat on github and show it to you

Comment: Just want to know, is it appropriate to use rooms for private chat? one on one chat.

Comment: Depends how private you want it to be. I think WebSockets over secure connections is fine, discussions would be private to whichever sockets  are in the same room and the server. To go even further, you could use something like WebRTC to set up a direct connection between two clients, letting them chat without going through the server at all (once the initial set up is done).

Comment: You said something about `.join(someString)`, Im trying to implement this, or do I create a new Room and store it on mongodb?

Comment: On the server side, you can call `socket.join(someString)` on a client's socket to join them to a room that has the identifier `someString`. I'm not sure what you mean by storing the room, the rooms won't persist past server shut down. The docs over here might help - http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#rooms

Comment: I meant store the room in a document itself for example `var room = new Room(); ` then `room.name="unique";`, because it is unique, plus i probably need to store the messages as well. What is your thought on this?

Comment: Im still confused on how to solve this room problem. What if I have thousands of users? your code will put all of the users in one room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101950/discussion-between-james-hiew-and-jack-moscovi).

Answer (score 0):

You can create room at server runtime, I used both users id as room id, Ex : '100-200' for demo purpose. May be you can use some more complex approach.